# C Language - Getting %Cpu for each process

Tags: c, process, cpu, ps

I'm currently working on a "ps aux" in C language. Everything is okay except the %CPU. I have no idea how to get it, when I calculate it with the times given in /proc/pid/stat I obtain a different result from the "ps aux" command. Any idea on how to get it ?

Edit : I need it to be instant like the "ps aux" command, I want to avoid a method using a sleep

Comment: What *do* you get? What do you *expect*? And *how* do you read and calculate the percentage?

Comment: It's not possible without sleep. cpu stats are always given as an incrementing value since starting of the process/of the machine. You can do a short sleep, but you always need two probes and calculate the difference